# Unable to Authorise Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

When loading up the Cloud Shell from the Cloud Console, I am prompted with the message: 'To properly run gcloud commands in your Cloud Shell, you must authorise the Cloud Shell'

[Error Message Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDHOa.png)

Upon clicking authorise, it opens a new Window that says connecting showing a white screen which automatically closes after a few seconds and takes me back to the same message:

[Connecting... Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xdul.png)

Tried with a few different accounts in our GSuite tenancy, that all have permission for Google Cloud Console and the same occurs.

Comment: Enable the Chrome debugger (F12). Do you see any error messages?

Comment: I believe there may be a few things to consider here: Do you have any kind of popup blocker that is preventing the OAuth window? Have you tried deleting the cache? Are you using a VPN? Do you have any setting on GSuite that may prevent Cloud Shell to authenticate?

Comment: It would be good if you check from a terminal where you are already authenticated whether you can connect to Cloud Shell using `gcloud alpha cloud-shell ssh`.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've had a look in the debugger and get this error: 
error: "invalid_request"
error_description: "Account restricted"

This would suggest to me it's something to do with a GSuite restriction, however I have since enabled everything possible for user I'm trying with

Comment: @Ajordat thanks for the advice, nope it works fine on my personal account in the same browser/network, which would suggest it's something to do with GSuite.

Comment: @cookie563 I guess that by personal account you mean on an account unrelated to GSuite and with another project right? Anyways, go to your GSuite settings and check if "Additional services without individual control" is turned off. If it is, try to use Cloud Shell having that setting turned on.

Comment: @Ajordat correct - it was using an account unrelated to GSuite.  I've temporarily turned all services on for the account I use, and it still hasn't made a difference. There does seem to be a related/unrelated issue which I've raised with support whereby an account still has access to a service that is disabled - I've tagged my Cloud Shell problem onto the case in the hope theres some relation.

Comment: @cookie563 Since it doesn't seem like anyone else can relate to this issue, I believe this should be handled with the support ticket you have already opened.